# Which Forum to Post Questions about CUPS

Tags: discussion, scope

What is the recommended forum site for Cups Common Unix Printing System forums (ask question-receive an answer) for new users to Linux using Cups within Qiana Cinn.

I have tried to log in to Cups forum and have not received a conformation via e-mail. This site might be geared to Super Users or Administrators?
To clarify my request,ideally I wish to contact informed users who can respond to general Cups questions and at the same time have a fairly knowledgeable base to receive an answer.

I have posted two inquires in the Linux Mint forum regarding Cups with fairly simple Cups questions with no answers? This leads me to wonder if I'm selecting the right forum?

I have just learned a little bit about Tags from this site. I will see if the Linux Mint Forum has this feature and use it. Your response(s) will be welcomed.

Comment: Did you try its official mail list: http://www.cups.org/lists.php?LIST=cups

Comment: My experience with CUPS is that there is no single entity beyond the forum that @Gnouc posted, and so you have to adjust your approach. I would recommend casting a wide net with your questions by listing them here on U&L and possibly ServerFault. Without knowing the specifics I can't give you much more advice then that. You might have to break up your single problem into smaller issues and put these on the most appropriate SE site too. And I'd also post them on any other forum you can think of, such as Linux Mint etc.

Comment: Thank you. Being new to stack exchange is daunting.This is the correct forum to ask a question with the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing a specific problem with CUPS, you can ask on [the main site](http://unix.stackexchange.com). CUPS issues are perfectly on topic here. Just make sure that your question follows the [site guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

This site is not geared to sysdamins or professionals. We welcome all users, irrespective of their level of knowledge. The questions here cover a very wide variety of issues from the newbie to the professional so feel very free to ask.

Comment: Thank You.Good feedback.I'm getting the idea.This is a good site.